# Accessing a member of an Object of template class

Tags: c++, class, object

Consider the following macro:

```
#define hash<k1,v1> abc
```

Now by some how, I have the instance of `abc` with me and now I want to assign a value to `v1` using `abc`, how can i do that.

I tried to do `abc->v1 = 10;`
I also tried `abc.v1 = 10;` 
but both of them didn't work. Please provide a simple solution.

**Please see this updated problem:**
Consider a macro as:

```
#define mac<a,b> abc
```

I have a function that has the return type as of `abc` type.
Say `xyz = func()`
Now with the help of `xyz`, I want to access a and assign some value to a,say

```
a = 10;
```

How can access the variable '`a`', and assign it the value using `xyz`.

Comment: Show us your code, we can't see any variable type here, if you don't know whether abc is a pointer, how could we tell without seeing its definition ?

Comment: What is supposed do your MACRO ?

Comment: For `std::hash`, access would be something like `abc[key] = value;`.

Comment: *"didn't work"* is not a helpful description - what exactly happens? post any relevant error messages and behavior

Comment: say 'xyz' is the instance of abc, then can we do xyz->v1 or xyz.v1 ?

Comment: that macro decl doesn't at least generate a *warning*?? That's surprising, and not a ringing endorsement for your preprocessor, whatever it is.

Comment: @aameraamer These macro definitions canot be _"considered"_, since that's not valid preprocessor code.

Answer (score 5):

You have the preprocessor macro definition backward. If you want `abc` to be expanded to (replaced with) `hash<k1, v1>` then it should defined the opposite way:

```
#define abc hash<k1, v1>
```

Then you can do e.g.

```
abc xyz;
```

And that will be the same as

```
hash<k1, v1> xyz;
```

Also note that this isn't a very good use of preprocessor macros, I recommend you use type-aliases instead:

```
using abc = hash<k1, v1>;
```

Then `abc` is an actual type-name that can be used as any other type.

Answer (score 0):

By your macro definition, `abc` refers to either the class `hash<k1, v1>` or function `hash<k1, v1>`, neither of which allows a member access using `->` or `.` syntax.

If you have a class `hash<k1, v1>` which has static members, you should use the `::` syntax to access the members by:

```
hash<k1, v1>::v1
// or
abc::v1
```

Or you should have an instance of `abc`:

```
abc xyz;
xyz.v1 = ...;
```

To state the obvious, if `hash<k1, v1>` refers to a function instead of a class, there is no member to access, so there is no way.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: v1 is **not** a variable. You seem to have some very fundamental problems understanding the code you write. v1 is a template parameter. "Accessing v1" means the same as "accessing string", especially since v1 could actually **be** string. It's nonsense. There are of course parameters that are numbers, but then it's the same again: accessing v1 would be the same as accessing 3. Not a variable, only a value.

Second: How you access something in a variable of "type" abc depends on how you access something in a variable of type hash. I'm not sure what hash is, std::hash has only one parameter, but if it behaves like std::map, you would usually access something by []-brackets.

Let's do an example:

```
#define MyMap std::map<string, string>

MyMap create_some_map(){
    MyMap result;
    result["name"] = "john";
    return result;
}

int main(){

    MyMap some_map = create_some_map();
    std::cout << some_map["name"] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Not that hard wasn't it?

If MyMap was a replacement for std::pair, you would access elements by some_map.first = ... and some_map.second = ... et cetera. If MyMap is some matrix type like a matrix from the Eigen library, you would probably access by like some_map(i,j) = 4.

Again, what a macro does is to replace some of your code before it is compiled. Nothing else. Usually I wouldn't mention it, but your question makes me think that you don't realize that.

That said, you should have a very good reason if you use such macros. Wouldn't recommend it under normal circumstances. If used wrong, macros can be quite bad. Use them when they do really really save you work and only if you absolutely understand what you do. Which I think you don't, sorry, but please read into that subject. Coding without understanding how it works will only cause frustration.

Also, can only agree with the answer of Some programmer dude, "using" is far better than macros in this situation. Just to mention this twice.